# imagemagick php HEIC

Tags: imagemagick, heic

I have an ubuntu 2.0 with NGINX and imagemagick 7 running, I was able to get HEIC support in imagemagick and can convert an HEIC file at the prompt, but php still throws an error imagemagick can not support HEIC files. Any ideas?

Comment: If your question is about PHP and **Imagick** (PHP ImageMagick extension), you should add those tags. Also, you might add the output from `phpinfo()` Also, you should show what changes you have made in your `php.ini` file to support the Imagick extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-installing PHP ImageMagick extension with PECL and it worked